# Running C++ CLR Visual Studio 2005 application as administrator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

Is there a way to get Administrator rigths on a C++ CLR project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional edition?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You sure you want to use a 15-year old tool chain? Asked the programmer who routinely uses GCC 3?

Comment: It's very easy to create CLR projects. I think it's easier than VS 2019...

Comment: You can start Visual Studio in administrator mode, but I wouldn't suggest it.  The first thing you'll notice is that drag/drop from Explorer will stop working.

Comment: It's not clear what "rights on a project" mean.  Do you mean that the project compiles to an EXE, and you want Windows to prompt for Admin rights when that EXE is launched?

Comment: Yes! That is what I want.

Comment: Good enough for me. Use the tool that works best for you.